# Repeated false-flag comments and votes, how to respond/reply?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm faced with a user who picks a small element of my question, posts an "answer" as a comment and (likely) down votes, and sometimes will vote to close as duplicate of something which does not answer my actual question but may address that small element cited in the comment.

I feel that these are at a minimum "false flags" and disruptive, and I feel that there has been a pattern of this.

There are two examples below. Should I start flagging these?

For the first one I've responded by editing the question to explain why the proposed duplicate isn't even close and left two polite comments. The next day the same thing was done in the second question, so I don't know how to respond differently.

1. [Why doesn't MAHLI get to be in Curiosity selfies?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42025/why-doesnt-mahli-get-to-be-in-curiosity-selfies) 2. [Why do these two Hubble Space Telescope star cameras point in nearly the same direction, and what's the other window for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42038/why-do-these-two-hubble-space-telescope-star-cameras-point-in-nearly-the-same-di?noredirect=1#comment137501_42038)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should flag things like this if you genuinely feel that's the case. You're probably over-reacting though, but don't worry, it's a moderators role to take a balanced and impartial view.

You might find doing basic research before asking your questions results in fewer downvotes

I also refer you to https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1420/20636

If you feel that What I consider to be full, but abbreviated answers to your questions are answering only a tiny part of your question, then perhaps you're trying to ask too much in a single question, or it's just your contrived questions are just too [clever](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1429/20636) and I'm missing the hidden point you're trying to discuss on this Q+A site.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not necessarily saying uhoh's questions are too clever or contrived, but they sometimes could be clearer, and I think both parties taking a step back and giving each other the benefit of the doubt would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you know an answer, write a proper answer.  That's just good for everyone, and you will earn upvotes.

---

We've all written questions that aren't as clear to others as we thought it would be.  It's okay to ask for clarification on such questions.

Questions that have the potential to be fixed should be clarified instead of closed.  It is way too easy to close a question, and hard to re-open questions.  Voting to close is for those questions with little chance to become acceptable.

---

The two questions aren't duplicates of each other.  Sure, they're the same "style" of question, but they are completely different spacecraft on completely different missions.  Voting to close as a duplicate is not appropriate here.

---

Finally, *both* parties in the original questions seemed to personally attack each other.  I'm not sure if that was intended, but that's the way things came across.

Comment: I didn't ask about personal attacks, but since you've brought it up could you link to some place where I "seem to personally attack" someone? Without a supporting link there's no way for anyone to judge the validity of that statement.